# Homebrew MariaDB 10.4.13 not found - forced updated to 10.5.5 and now I cannot start my database

Tags: mysql, macos, mariadb, homebrew, mariadb-10.4

I am unable to find MariaDB version 10.4.13 using brew. After reinstalling by uninstalling and installing (critical mistake) Homebrew upgraded my version to 10.5.5

Now I am getting the following error:

> 020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE4.2 crc32 instructions
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 268435456, chunk size = 134217728
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.4.13.
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>
> 2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have still have my datadir somewhere outside of the /var/log/mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I found round this was to backup my `/var/lib/mysql` and `/var/lib/mariadb` directories by renaming them, then creating them as empty directories. I'm aware this isn't an option for many, if you're still in development and working on seed data this should work for you.

There has been some talk about just removing log files from these directories and thus preserving data though I haven't tried this.

Log files reportedly removed that fixed this issue:

```
/var/lib/mysqld/ib_logfile0
/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control
```

referenced from https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/93

Comment: Thanks Spikie. Unfortunately the damage has already been done and that's not an option for me, but I appreciate your time.

Comment: Thanks — this worked for me. Not sure what happened but possibly the redo logs were damaged after an upgrade to 10.5.5 or incompatible. After deleting the redo logs, mariadb started successfully. This was on my development environment, so it wasn't a problem. So far it looks like it has recovered perfectly fine.

Comment: I ended up resorting to Time Machine to restore my previous installation. Since this solution worked for you, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: The directory with the lof-iles on macos Big Sur/mariadb when installed using homebrew are located here: 
`/usr/local/var/mysql`

Comment: +1 for just deleting log files - for me using mariadb on MacOS Big Sur, just deleting /usr/local/var/mysql/ib_logfile* fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Don't do this. You'll loose data.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `2020-08-14 20:33:07 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.4.13.` is the key aspect.

What has happened is the server has crashed (force killed by either the user or the OS), and when the new version was installed it doesn't recognise the old redo log format.

The solution is to start a MariaDB-10.4 instance on the same data directory and then shut it down cleanly. Cleanness can be identified by seeing "Shutdown complete" as the last message in the logs.

After than, you can start any newer version of MariaDB on the same datadir.

As downgrading is potentially difficult in some packaging systems, you should with the right permissions run the `mariadb:10.4` Docker Official Image container using the same datadir as the volume `/var/lib/mysql` and achieve the same thing.

Do not go deleting Innodb or Aria files. They store changes that haven't been written to the table space and potentially internal changes. You can quite easily get a corrupted database by removing them. And in 10.11+, it won't start without those files to highlight was a bad choice in deleting them was made.